# Controlling low voltage circuit with wall outlet power

Tags: relay, control

I'm basically looking for a reverse relay: I want to switch around 5V with wall outlet power (230V 50Hz in my country). When wall power goes out, the low-voltage circuit should open. I don't have space to use a phone charger / wall wart, and I'd like to avoid anything involving just a diode + resistor which would heat up and waste energy.

Do these kind of relays exist? I previously thought this kind of thing could be accomplished easily but now that I'm looking, I can't find anything.

Comment: USB wall warts get pretty darn small! The important thing is they are listed by credible third party testing labs, so they are safe.  Something you build won't be.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do?  What is the purpose for this circuit?  Why not just use a 5V adapter?  It will naturally go off when the power goes off...

Comment: Your constraints are also puzzling - if you don't have room for a USB adapter then a 230VAC relay isn't going to be much smaller, if at all.  More details here would get you a much better answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm basically looking for a reverse relay.

No. You're looking for a relay. You just need one with a 230 V AC coil.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsurCo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The relay contact will open when mains power is lost.*

Don't omit the fuse.

Comment: You might have problems with low-load conditions here, though. Ideally, find a relay with gold or rhodium contacts, not tungsten.

Comment: Fuse is nice, but PE and overvoltage protection aren't optional either...

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev PE isn't needed if you build it to class II, and overvoltage protection for a simple relay would be excessive if the fuse is chosen properly (slow blow type, low value) to protect everything from the accompanying overcurrent